# What are MUI transition props?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

what are React MUI transition props? I only found "transform" :

```
transition: theme.transitions.create(["color", "transform"], {
duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
})
```

but where can I find other options?

I've searched the MUI docs but I found only "transform"

Answer (score 0):

since you didnt provide any additional context, here is a pretty general answere:

The `theme.transitions.create` method is a helper function provided by Material-UI that allows you to create custom CSS transitions. It takes two arguments: "props" and "options".

The props argument is either a string or an array of strings that specify the CSS properties that should be transitioned. In your example, the color and transform properties are being transitioned.

The options argument is an optional object that can contain several properties to further customize the transition. The duration property specifies the duration of the transition, and in your example, it is set to the value of `theme.transitions.duration.shortest`. This means that the transition will have the shortest duration defined in your theme.

There are other properties that you can set in the options object, such as easing, which specifies the easing function for the transition, and delay, which specifies the delay before the transition starts.

Comment: I'm asking about that 'CSS properties that should be transitioned'. What are those?

Comment: normally when you define a css transition, you give it a length, a function (linear etc.), and a property that the transition should apply to. If you say "all" for the property, the transition effect will aply to all properties of your component. If you mention specific css properties like "transform" or "color", then only these properties will transition, the others will still change their appearance instantly, without transition. The same is true with MUI here.

Comment: Example:

"transition: 2s linear color;" ... You would normally put the property at the front though, so: "transition: color 2s linear;" ... Or for your mui case "transition: transform color 2s linear"